# Kodi hangs on startup from both CLI and GUI

Tags: kodi

I have installed latest version of Kodi in my Raspberry Pi OS. When I try to start Kodi either by trying to execute from the terminal or from the application menu, the system hangs, seems frizzed. I need to reboot the device to get to the normal state again.

Here's a snapshot of hanged state

[image]

Please suggest me, what am I missing?

**update:** I have found this on Kodi forum that Kodi needs the Fake GL driver, and then I set it, still not working. Here's the take from the forum [topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=251645),

> Kodi on the Raspberry Pi 4 will only function if you are using the
> Open Source drivers! This is the "GL (Fake KMS) OpenGL desktop driver
> with fake KMS" on raspi-config, which is currently the default on the
> Raspbian images for the RPi 4. If you select the Broadcom/Legacy
> driver, it won't work!

Comment: Which Pi, I had the same problem on my Pi4, it's OK with a Pi3

Comment: Pi 4, yes. One with the 4GB RAM.

Comment: Have you tried using the LibreELEC cut down OS that's the recommended route for the Pi4 and will be my next step when some new parts arrive

Comment: Didn't try, no. Tried with Raspberry Pi OS only. Okay, I will look into it.

Comment: You're connected to the pi via VNC, does it do the same when looking at the pi via a monitor/tv? Some applications will only/or by default output via the hdmi connection which would explain why the vnc session seems to hang.

Comment: I didn't connect to a monitor over hdmi. How do change kodi to show output over VNC?

Comment: I'd connect it to a monitor first and make sure there isn't another issue as well. Have a look here (https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=339122) for using kodi over vnc but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. You aren't likely to get a good picture with it.

Comment: @rohtua, I just want to set up Kodi over VNC, not watch it actually.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that installing Kodi using the LibreELEC cutdown OS works just fine on the Pi4 as I've just done it, mine was the 2gb memory version. I used the guide here [LibrELEC Wiki](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/)

Comment: Please note that I am using VNC to view Kodi, I am not using HDMI. What did you use? I can go with LibreELEC but I am afraid maybe that's not the issue here.

Comment: HDMI I've no idea if I could install a vnc server with LibreELEC

Comment: Alright, I will let you know if I have any update.

Comment: A quick Google indicates a kodi vnc add on is available so it should work

Comment: Can you please tell me the plugin name? I looked into apt-cache but couldn't find anything related to vnc with Kodi

Comment: The LibreELEC addon is dispmanx according to Google, installing is done in Kodi by selecting the addon in the LibreELEC repository

Comment: Exactly, but as you see, I am unable to open Kodi for the first time. I will get a HDMI and connect to a monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting a monitor or TV using HDMI helps. Like people mentioned in the comments, I was using VNC, so kodi was unable to start. No issues with HDMI.

Comment: This also resolved my issue. Connecting through VNC and running KODI will freeze the os.